# MVC 3 Install problem

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Somebody allready installed MVC 3? I have Windows 7 + VS 2010. Trying to install with Web Platform Installer,- its show me "OK" but there isn't Web MVC3 Application in New Project template =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Somebody allready installed MVC 3?

Yes.

Try [downloading the installer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d2928bc1-f48c-4e95-a064-2a455a22c8f6&displaylang=en) and running it locally. Make sure you have removed any previous RC versions you might have installed. The new project template shows when creating a new Web Application (not Web Site).

Comment: Thx alot. Everything is fine :)

Comment: I don't know. It show me it installed, but didn't display anywhere (VS project templage), and i can choose to instal MVC 3 more and more and more times in Web Platform Installer. Now all is ok, when installed with .exe in link page.